# ASP.NET Core - Any reason not to use a parameter object with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I like the DI feature of ASP.NET Core, but am finding that some of my classes end up with huge constructor parameter signatures...

```
public class Foo {
  private IBar1 _bar1;
  private IBar2 _bar2;
  // lots more here...

  public Foo(IBar1 bar1, IBar2 bar2, lots more here...) {
    _Bar1 = bar1;
    _Bar2 = bar2;
    // ...
  }

  public DoSomething() {
    // Use _bar1
  }
}
```

In case this looks like a code smell, it's worth pointing out that any controller is going to use AutoMapper, an email service and 2 or 3 managers related to ASP.NET Identity, so I have 4 or 5 dependencies before I start injecting a single repository. Even if I only use 2 repositories, I can end up with 6 or 7 dependencies without actually violating any SOLID principles.

I was wondering about using a parameter object instead. I could create a class that has a public property for every injected dependency in my application, takes a constructor parameter for each one, and then just inject this into each class instead of all the individual Bars...

```
public class Foo {
  private IAllBars _allBars;

  public Foo(IAllBars allBars) {
    _allBars = allBars;
  }

  public DoSomething() {
    // Use _allBars.Bar1
  }
}
```

The only disadvantage I can see is that it would mean that every class would have every dependency injected into it via the parameter object. In theory, this sounds like a bad idea, but I can't find any evidence that it would cause any problems.

Anyone any comments? Am I letting myself into potential trouble by trying to make my constructor code neater?

Comment: @ThomasWeller This was all simplified code, not real class names. The freds are largely repositories and services, and `Jim` was merely a name off the top of my head. I didn't want to confuse my question with the actual scenario in hand, as it's irrelevant.

Comment: The usual convention is to use Foo and Bar to indicate arbitrary things, not Jim, Fred and Alfred.

Comment: @ThomasWeller True, but I never use them due to the rather unpleasant background to both. I'm so used to using Jim and Fred that I forgot others wouldn't be!

Comment: @ThomasWeller OK, so having looked it up, it seems I'm mixing up fubar, which has unpleasant connotations with foo and bar which don't. My mistake. I edited the question to use the more common terms.

Comment: I really don't see any problem with having multiple parameters in your constructor. But if they really get too big, then you're probably doing something wrong...or your controller is doing too much.

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing sounds like the [service locator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern), and while it seems tempting to simplify your code by eliminating all those constructor parameters, it usually ends up hurting maintainability in the long run. Check out Mark Seemann's post [Service Locator violates encapsulation](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/10/26/service-locator-violates-encapsulation/) for more details about why it should be avoided.

Generally, when you find yourself with a class with dozens of constructor parameters, it means that class might have too many responsibilities. Can it be decomposed into a number of smaller classes with narrower goals? Rather than introducing a "catch-all" class that knows about *everything*, maybe there's a complex part of your application that you can abstract behind a [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

Sometimes, you do end up with large *coordinator* classes that have many dependencies and that's okay in certain circumstances. However, if you have many of these it's usually a design smell.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, interesting. The point about preconditions is true enough, you wouldn't know which of the properties of the parameter object (PO) were actually needed and which weren't. Having said that, as they would all be injected into the PO itself, I'm not sure that would matter. Needs some more thought.

Comment: In the context of DI, hiding multiple dependencies behind a new (simplified) abstraction is known as the [Facade Services refactoring](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/). Do note, however, that `IAllBars` does not *hide* the dependencies, which means the complexity of `Foo` is not reduced.

Comment: @Steven Thanks for the link, very interesting. I think the first thing to do is revisit the code and see if I have too much going on in each class. Thing is, by the time I've injected general stuff, like AutoMapper, the email service and a couple of managers needed for use with ASP.NET Core identity, I'm already up to 4 or 5 dependencies before I inject a single repository. I'm not convinced that having 6 or 7 dependencies is necessarily a code smell.

Comment: In my book, 7 dependencies is certainly a code smell. Fixing a legacy code base to make classes simpler (by removing cross cutting concerns for instance) can be daunting, however. I know. Been there, done that.

Comment: @Steven Well, out of those 7, only 2 are specific to the class in question, the rest are boilerplate technicalities, common to any controller. Other than creating a base controller that injects these, and having inherited controllers inject just what they need (which might not be a bad idea now I think about it), I don't see how to get away with less.

Comment: If 5 of those dependencies are boilerplate, this rests my case :) how to fix however, is a different ball game and impossible to answer without seeing more details.

Comment: @Steven OK, got the point :)